Glass strips on concrete floor is breaking
I have concrete floor in old home, where glass strips are used to partition the concrete floor like this Glass Strip

These strips are breaking from top and I am afraid might pinch foot some time.
What can I do to prevent breaking and becoming it sharp. Can I put silicon or some rubber or anything on it?

picture missing

You have a link to an article. Whats required is an image. Take a photo with your phone and post it.

what are we looking at in the picture? ... it is unclear what is what

Are you certain that's glass?

yes,its glass, was installed in front of my eyes when i was kid , picture has greyish part is concrete and line between is glass strip, this strip lop portion is weathering and breaking @Huesmann
